# How to define custom gradient for keras layer with tensorflow 1.14

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement gradient reversal layer in tf.keras (tf ver 1.14). I defined a custom gradient using tf.custom_gradient but the grad function is never called and the result is wrong.

I am using the following to test the layer

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as k
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np

@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(x):
    result = x
    def custom_grad(dy):
        grad = tf.negative(dy)
        return grad
    return result, custom_grad

class GradientReversal(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(GradientReversal, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
    return custom_op(inputs)


a = Input(shape=(2,))
b = GradientReversal()(a)
c = Dense(1)(b)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=c)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')

@tf.function
def test():  
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    out = model(np.ones((1, 2)))
  gradients = tape.gradient(out, model.trainable_variables)
  return gradients

print(test())
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was supposed to use GradientReversal layer after the Dense to get the result I want.